# find the number of exporter-importer pairs

Tags: combinatorics

I have $26$ countries in my sample. From these $26$ countries $24$ are exporters. I built country-pairs (exporter-importer) in the statistical program. I obtained $600$ pairs. I would like to understand the logic behind it. From high-school class, I know the Newton formula. However, I don't know how to modify it in this case. Using Newton's formula when $n=26$ and $k=2$, I got $325$, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Assuming that all countries are importers (which you don't say) and assuming that no country can be paired with itself (which you also don't say) then there are $24$ choices of exporter and $25$ choices of importer and $24\times 25=600$.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Don't be so quick to try to jump to "formulas" that you don't understand.  This follows from something far more fundamental, the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Answer (score 1):

The formula $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$ counts the number of ways of selecting $k$-element subsets from a set with $n$ elements.  Therefore, $$\binom{26}{2} = 325$$ is the number of ways of selecting a pair of countries from the $26$ countries.  However, the order of the elements in a set does not matter.  In this case, order does matter since you are counting ordered pairs: (exporter, importer).  As @lulu indicated in the comments, you arrived at $600$ by assuming that each of the $24$ possible exporters could export its goods to each of the other $25$ countries, giving $24 \cdot 25 = 600$ possible (exporter, importer) pairs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Now I got it!